# HERE maps for Javascript API: Set map bounds to cluster bounds

Tags: here-api

I am using HERE maps for Javascript API. I know how to set the bounds of a map to a marker group, yet how would I retrieve the bounds of a cluster (I am using the clustering Provider with a Theme) and set the map bounds accordingly?

Comment: For the user who downvoted this question: It would be nice to see your comment, why you decided to downvote. In my opinion it is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering Provider has method [getRootGroup()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.clustering.Provider.html#getRootGroup) to retrieve root group for all provider's objects. This group you can use then to get it's bounding box:

```js
// assuming map & clusteringProvider have been instantiated before
map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
  bounds: clusteringProvider.getRootGroup().getBoundingBox()
})
```

**Note:** clustering calculation doesn't happen synchronously, therefore you don't get correct bounds immediately. You should listen to provider's `update` event to see when the clustering is done.

Here you can find working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zb6gaof/) example.

**Note2**: the example works only with `GRID` and `FASTGRID` strategies. (see [H.clustering.Provider.Strategy](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.clustering.Provider.html#.Strategy) for more details about strategies).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and example Tomas. Worked out excellently for me. I somehow missed the .getRootGroup() function in the documentation.